# Correct way to define a method on C#

Tags: c#

Hi guys I am pretty new on C# and I would like to make this code works the right way and understand why is not running the right way.

So I have this.

```
class PayrollRunner
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // use Employee without tax
            Employee john = new Employee(1, "John Doe", 20000, false);
            john.printInformation();

            // use Employee with tax
            Employee jane = new Employee(2, "Jane Doe", 36000);
            jane.printInformation();

            // use WeeklyEmployee without tax
           // WeeklyEmployee jack = new WeeklyEmployee(3, "Jack Deer", 18500, false);
            //jack.printInformation();

            // use WeeklyEmployee with tax
            //WeeklyEmployee jen = new WeeklyEmployee(4, "Jen Deer", 18000);
           // jen.printInformation();

            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    class Employee
    {
        private int employeeId;
        private string fullName;
        private float salary;
        private bool taxDeducted;

        public Employee(int employeeId, string fullName, float salary, bool taxDeducted)
        {
            this.employeeId = employeeId;
            this.fullName = fullName;
            this.salary = salary;
            this.taxDeducted = taxDeducted;
        }

        public Employee(int employeeId, string fullName, float salary)
        {
            this.employeeId = employeeId;
            this.fullName = fullName;
            this.salary = salary;
            this.taxDeducted = true;
        }

        public float getNetSalary()
        {
            float netSalary;
            float tax = 0.8;

            if (taxDeducted)
                {
                netSalary = salary * tax;

                }
            else
                {
                netSalary = salary;
                }

            return netSalary;
        }

        float netSalary = Employee.getNetSalary();

        public void printInformation()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(employeeId + " " + fullName + " earns " + 
          netSalary + " per month");

        }
    }
```

So I am expecting the following results on screen

1 John Doe earns 20000 per month
2 Jane Doe earns 28800 per month

But I am getting

1 John Doe earns 20000 per month
2 Jane Doe earns 36000 per month

I don't know how to define the method or maybe there is something else wrong, anybody would like to share its knowledge.

Thanks.

Comment: Well this code doesn' compile. Are you pasting your real code here?

Comment: Tip: Never use IEE-754 floating-point types (like `float`, `double`, `Single`) to store decimal numbers like currency amounts because they cannot exactly represent certain decimal values. They can only store approximate values. Either use `Decimal` or an integer type (to store integer cents).

Comment: Given that this won't run, it's hard to see how you're getting any results at all. Are you sure this is the right version of the code?

Comment: You also seem to be coding using Java standards. Is that where you've come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix is remove this line

```
float netSalary = Employee.getNetSalary();
```

and use this

```
public void printInformation()
{
    Console.WriteLine(employeeId + " " + fullName + " earns " + 
      getNetSalary() + " per month");
}
```

or create a property instead of method `getNetSalary()`

```
public float NetSalary
{
    get
    {
        float netSalary;
        float tax = 0.8;

        if (taxDeducted)
            {
            netSalary = salary * tax;

            }
        else
            {
            netSalary = salary;
            }

        return netSalary;
    }
}
```

then

```
public void printInformation()
{
        Console.WriteLine(employeeId + " " + fullName + " earns " + 
          NetSalary + " per month");
}
```

or calculate this salary once to improve performance

Comment: thanks mate this actually helped!!  So another question, for each class should I create a new file for it? or should I put it everything under the same main class, what is the correct way to deal with this?

Comment: There is no correct way to manage classes and files. It's a matter of individual preference. If your class becomes to large, you may choose to split your code across multiple files for readability purposes. It is entirely user preference. Some companies do however have coding standards which employees need to abide by.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't compile.
Calling *Employee.getNetSalary* cannot be compiled because *getNetSalary* is an instance method and cannot be called as a static method. You need an instance of the Employee class to call it.

To fix your problem you need to move the call to method *getNetSalary* inside the method *printInformation* and use a reference to the current instance (this) when calling it

This is your revised *printInformation*

```
public void printInformation()
{
    // Call on the class instance properties to execute the calc
    float netSalary = this.getNetSalary();
    Console.WriteLine($"{employeeId} {fullName} earns {netSalary:C} per month");

}
```

In this way *getNetSalary* works using the properties of the current instance of the employee.

A second tip, I suggest, is to remove the second constructor (the one that doesn't take a taxDeducted boolean) but write just one constructor setting a default for the *taxDeducted* property to true

```
public Employee(int employeeId, string fullName, float salary, bool taxDeducted = true)
{
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
    this.fullName = fullName;
    this.salary = salary;
    this.taxDeducted = taxDeducted;
}
```

Comment: float netSalary = Employee.getNetSalary(); this is the reason for compilation failure. Trying to access a non-static method

Comment: Yes that is the error message displayed by the compiler. I think that this is already known to the OP

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the class this way.

```
class Employee
    {
        private int employeeId;
        private string fullName;
        private float salary;
        private bool taxDeducted;

        public Employee(int employeeId, string fullName, float salary, bool taxDeducted=true)
        {
            this.employeeId = employeeId;
            this.fullName = fullName;
            this.salary = salary;
            this.taxDeducted = taxDeducted;
        }

        public float getNetSalary()
        {
            float tax = 0.8F;
            float salary = this.salary;
            if (taxDeducted)
                salary *= tax;
            return salary;
        }

        public void printInformation()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(employeeId + " " + fullName + " earns " + getNetSalary() + " per month");

        }
    }
```

then try it

```
Employee john = new Employee(1, "John Doe", 20000, false);
john.printInformation();

// use Employee with tax
Employee jane = new Employee(2, "Jane Doe", 36000);
jane.printInformation();
```

1 John Doe earns 20000 per month

2 Jane Doe earns 28800 per month

Answer (score 0):

I changed the fields to automatic properties. This helps if you need to bind your class in other apps. I capitalized the initial letter of methods and public properties to make VS happy. I made the GetNetSalary private. It won't be accessed outside of the class and I used it to set a new property, NetSalary. It is called in the constructor. I also got rid of Console.WriteLine in the class and provided an Override of .ToString. This disconnects the class from the User Interface and allows the class to migrate to other types of applications.

```
class PayrollRunner
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // use Employee without tax
        Employee john = new Employee(1, "John Doe", 20000, false);
        Console.WriteLine(john.ToString());

        // use Employee with tax
        Employee jane = new Employee(2, "Jane Doe", 36000);
        Console.WriteLine(jane.ToString());

        // use WeeklyEmployee without tax
        // WeeklyEmployee jack = new WeeklyEmployee(3, "Jack Deer", 18500, false);
        //jack.printInformation();

        // use WeeklyEmployee with tax
        //WeeklyEmployee jen = new WeeklyEmployee(4, "Jen Deer", 18000);
        // jen.printInformation();

        Console.Read();
    }
}

class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    public bool TaxDeducted { get; set; }
    public decimal NetSalary { get; set; }

    public Employee(int employeeId, string fullName, decimal salary, bool taxDeducted)
    {
        EmployeeId = employeeId;
        FullName = fullName;
        Salary = salary;
        TaxDeducted = taxDeducted;
        NetSalary = GetNetSalary(salary, taxDeducted);
    }
    public Employee(int employeeId, string fullName, decimal salary)
    {
        EmployeeId = employeeId;
        FullName = fullName;
        Salary = salary;
        TaxDeducted = true;
        NetSalary = GetNetSalary(salary, true);
    }
    private decimal GetNetSalary(decimal grossPay, Boolean taxable)
    {
        decimal netPay;
        decimal tax = 0.8M;
        if (TaxDeducted)
            netPay = grossPay * tax;
        else
            netPay = grossPay;

        return netPay;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{EmployeeId} {FullName} earns {NetSalary} per month";
    }
}
```

}